# Edition at the end of bib entry

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

:)

I would like to **change the edition entry** so that it sits **at the end of the bib entry (but, in case there is also an addendum entry before the addendum)**.

I am currently using a workaround "abusing" the addendum field for this very purpose, but with an increasing amount of literature, it would be great to have that organized more neatly.

MWE:

```
  \documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  headings=standardclasses,
  listof=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.00cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIB
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  sorting=nyvt,
  datamodel=customstyles,
  maxnames=25,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  usetranslator=true,
  alldates=terse,
  labeldate=year,
  dashed=false,
  doi=false,
  isbn=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[hidelinks, pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

% editor in parentheses
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}
\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,online]
  {title}{#1\isdot}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MAIN
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@collection{Karnath.2012,
    addendum = {(3., aktualisierte und erweiterte Auflage)},
    title = {Kognitive Neurowissenschaften},
    editor = {Karnath, Hans-Otto and Thier, Peter},
    place = {Berlin, Heidelberg},
    publisher = {Springer},
    year = {2012}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\parencite{Karnath.2012} 
\clearpage
\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc,title={Literaturverzeichnis}]
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This creates the desired format (but as said, is not really the correct way to use the fields)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `biblatex-ext` styles you can redefine the bibmacro `edition` to suppress the edition in its usual place. Then you just need to reinsert it in the desired position. (Here I chose to append the edition to the publisher, location [and date] details, because that seemed sensible and is towards the end of the entry, but you can pick another position, e.g. in `addendum+pubstate` as well).

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  headings=standardclasses,
  listof=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  sorting=nyvt,
  datamodel=customstyles,
  maxnames=25,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  usetranslator=true,
  alldates=terse,
  labeldate=year,
  dashed=false,
  doi=false,
  isbn=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[hidelinks, pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

% editor in parentheses
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}
\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,online]
  {title}{#1\isdot}

\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{edition}{}
\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{#1}
    {\setunit*{\locdatedelim}}
    {\setunit*{\locpubdelim}}%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \setunit*{\pubdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@collection{Karnath.2012,
  title     = {Kognitive Neurowissenschaften},
  editor    = {Karnath, Hans-Otto and Thier, Peter},
  location  = {Berlin and Heidelberg},
  publisher = {Springer},
  year      = {2012},
  edition   = {3., aktualisierte und erweiterte Auflage},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\autocite{Karnath.2012} 

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Literaturverzeichnis}]
\end{document}
```

[image: Karnath, Hans-Otto und Peter Thier (Hrsg.) (2012): Kognitive Neurowissenschaften. Berlin und Heidelberg: Springer. (3., aktualisierte und erweiterte Auflage).]

For numeric-only editions, `biblatex` prefers the raw number (as in `edition = {2},` instead of `edition = {2. Auflage}`,), but if you have to give a more specific designation like "3., aktualisierte und erweiterte Auflage", the "Auflage" should be included in the field.

Note that the standard styles don't know a `place` field, the city of the publisher goes into the `location` field (or `address` if you want BibTeX backwards compatibility).

Comment: Thanks so much @moewe works beautifully!